# Interpreting performance tests for non-zero check

Tags: javascript

I've recently again fallen into the trap of premature optimization, and hopefully climbed back out. However, on my short intermission, i've encountered something, which i'd like to confirm.

My very basic performance test yielded similar results on chrome (all variables are just declared globally, the first takes ~9ms, second ~7.5ms):

```
input = Array.from({ length: 1000000 }, () => Math.random() > 0.8 ? 0 : Math.random() * 1000000000 );
start = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  input[i] = input[i] === 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
console.log(performance.now() - start);
```

and

```
input = Array.from({ length: 1000000 }, () => Math.random() > 0.8 ? 0 : Math.random() * 1000000000 );
start = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  input[i] = ((input[i] | (~input[i] + 1)) >>> 31) & 1;
}
console.log(performance.now() - start);
```

When taking into account, that the loop and assignment itself is already taking a lot of time (~4.5ms), the second potentially takes ~33% less time, which is however far smaller gain than what i'd expect (and within measuring inaccuracy, e.g. on FireFox, both take much longer, and the second is ~33% worse).

Can i at this point conclude, that an optimization of the condition is already taking place, and a similar code change already being done, or am i falling for some mirage of a microbenchmark? In my mind, a branch of this category should be excessively more time consuming than the calculation.

I am primarily skeptical of my own reasoning, because i know, that these kinds of tests can very easily have skewed results for unforeseen reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's most likely an effect of measurement and JIT-compiler effects combined.

Especially the heuristik-driven [JIT-compiler in JS modern browsers have](https://codeburst.io/javascript-compiler-optimization-techniques-only-for-experts-58d6f5f958ca#4176) is that good, that you won't have any chance of visualizing the "real" performance benefit of the intuitively faster statement.

The variance in my browser is so high that both codes need approximately equal time (running in Opera), which underlines your effect in FF.

Be glad that you found that 1.5ms advantage, you won't see more.

Comment: I'll probably not use the "optimization", because it is far less readable, and not a factor off in speed, therefore within measuring accuracy (can't really determine which is faster). PS: reading the linked article, i saw the `node --trace-opt --tracedeopt`, and with that quickly noticed, that wrapping the for loop in an IIFE also speeds up the process, because there was a deoptimization step due to the `console.log` for me. I got more convinced, that it's all a mirage again, and actually measuring which is faster in a real world application can't be done with what i did.